# Magento PLugin Multi store Disable/Enable functionality

Tags: php, plugins, magento, e-commerce

I had developed an extension. Now my client after having another store within same magento platform (multistore functionality) wants to disable "extesnion" on one store and enable on other.

I am stuck, can't have whole day  reading magento docs, as I have other 3 clients/project ongoing, still want to help out this magento guy.

I would be happy if someone could give me answer to "How to make magento plugin to be available to turn on/off per store in multistore magento copy?"

I would also appreciate if anyone could just give me directions where to dig!

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find the previous question that answered a simple thing, hopefully someone can dredge it up. Basically, create a store-level configuration option to enable/disable functionality. Then, when invoking your new functionality (which I'm sure has been properly kept within your module's classes):

```
function doSomethingSpecial() {
    if(!$this->moduleIsEnabledForStore()) { return; }
    ... do your thing ...
}
```

There is no clean way to disable the module otherwise through Magento's default interfaces, but this is actually a very clean proxy.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: thank you, your answer certainly saved few hours of my and supposedly other's time!